# pretty url static files not loading

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm building a social network and my htaccess pretty url isn't loading the css/js/img/php files. The following rules work

```html
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^login$ index.php?act=login [NC]
RewriteRule ^register$ index.php?act=register [NC]
RewriteRule ^forgot$ index.php?act=forgot [NC]
```

But the following rule works but doesn't load the css/js/img

```html
RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/?$ index.php?act=profile&user=$1 [NC]
```

What I'm I doing wrong? I don't have a base url set. The home page url is

```html
http://localhost/myWebsite/source/
```

I also have the following logic in my controller which is included at the top of the index page

```html
    if ($isLogged == true) {
        // check if page request set
        if (isset($_GET['act'])) {
            // valid pages
            $pgeArray = array("stories", "hashtags", "media", "user", "search");
            // check if page is valid
            if (in_array($_GET['act'], $pgeArray)) {
                // get page name request
                $pgeReq = $_GET['act'];
            }else {
                // show registration page
                $pgeReq = "home";
            }
        }else {
            // show registration page
            $pgeReq = "home";
        }
    }
    else {
        // check if page request set
        if (isset($_GET['act'])) {
            // valid pages
            $pgeArray = array("register", "login", "forgot");
            // check if page is valid
            if (in_array($_GET['act'], $pgeArray)) {
                // get page name request
                $pgeReq = $_GET['act'];
            }else {
                // show registration page
                $pgeReq = "login";
            }
        }else {
            // show registration page
            $pgeReq = "login";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Well, what URL is actually loaded for those css and js files and what are they rewritten to? _You_ claim they are rewritten...

Comment: The working 3 will add the pretty url after source/ eg source/login

Comment: Either use absolute paths for css/js or use `<base...>` tag in your HTML

Comment: yes such a simpler solution thanks

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do is specify a base url `<base href="http://localhost/myWebsite/source/" />`
`